# How oauth works with major platforms eg. FB and Google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, server-side, mobile-application

We've seen many mobile apps where we are allowed to log-in to their service with 3rd party social media platforms eg. Google, Facebook

[image]

However, as Im seeking to build my own platform that uses third party SSO, I have been reading up on OAuth requiring an authentication server. This diagram (emphasis mine)

[image]

What Im unsure about is where does Google and FB come in?

Comment: They would be the Authorization Server in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you describe {Google, Facebook} acts as an **identity provider**. More precisely they act as **OAuth 2.0 authorization servers**.
In case of Google they also conform their Oauth2 implementation to the OpenId specification allowing them to provide you with both authentication and authorisation.

No need to know the ins and outs of the Oauth2 protocol,  just keep in mind that it's a protocol that guarantees that you are authenticated with the right permission.

Google provides good [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver) of the protocol flow and most importantly a [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to understand it in live.

Note that we also have different kind of identity providers to implement SSO. We have SAML identity providers such as Okta or Keycloak. Different protocol, different purpose (more enterprise oriented).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. In the case of identity providers such as FB or Google, they would authenticate the user and provide a token which we could create in our database and perform future authentications. Is there a way to ensure that Its actually FB and Google creating the token and not some server generating a random token for the first time? Because prior to the token being created, is there any check we can do at our script to ensure the token was enerated from Google or FB?

Comment: @Nederealm The easiest way to check if a token is valid, is to make an API request (such as for basic user details), and see what response you get. If the token is not valid or not genuine, you can expect to get an error. Valid tokens can not be “guessed” or otherwise created from the outside. Plus, if you use the server-side login flow, where you exchange a `code` parameter for a token via an API call, you are sure where your response came from to begin with.

Comment: I would add that the Oauth protocol imposes TLS/SSL connection to the identity provider making hard for an atacker to eavedrops the connection. At some point you indeed need to trust clever guys/girls on the solidity of their protocol implementation. that why you should also look for certifications on the chosen identity provider.